# How to assign variable to PROMPT_COMMAND

Tags: bash, prompt

How can I increment a variable assigning its value to PROMPT_COMMAND variable?

Inside .bashrc I created variable `a` and assigned value to 0
and then added this

```
a=0
PROMPT_COMMAND=`((a++))`
```

When I echo PROMPT_COMMAND it shows that it is empty.

Comment: `PROMPT_COMMAND` is empty in your code because `((a++))` doesn't print anything, only increments `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with

```
a=0
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -n $((a++))'
```

after you open a new shell (or source .bashrc by calling `. ~/.bashrc`.